# Why does sizeThatFits() return a size that is too small?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm learning swift with cs193p and I have a problem with `UITextView.sizeThatFits(...)`. It should return a recommended size for popover view to display an [int] array as a text. As you can see in Paul Hegarty's example (https://youtu.be/gjl2gc70YHM?t=1h43m17s), he gets perfectly-fit popover window without scrollbar. I'm using almost the same code that was in this lecture, but instead i've got this:

[image]

the `text` string equals `[100]`, but the `sizeThatFits()` method is returning a size that is too small to display it nicely, even though there is plenty of free space.
It is getting a bit better after I've added some text, but still not precise and with the scrollbar:

[image]

Here is the part of the code where the size is being set:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        if textView != nil && presentingViewController != nil {
        // I've added these outputs so I can see the exact numbers to try to understand how this works
            print("presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size = \(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size)")
            print("sizeThatFits = \(textView.sizeThatFits(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size))")
            return textView.sizeThatFits(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size)
        } else { return super.preferredContentSize }
    }
    set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
}
```

What should I do so this will work in the same way as in the lecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are 16 pt margins between the label and its parent view.  You need to take that into account when returning the preferred size of the popover.

You should try both of the following:

- Add 32 to the width that's returned from `preferredContentSize`
- In Interface Builder, clear the layout constraints on your `UILabel`, then re-add top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints and make sure that "Constrain to Margins" option is not enabled.

Finally, instead of overriding `preferredContentSize`, you can simply set the `preferredContentSize` when your view is ready to display, and you can ask Auto Layout to choose the best size:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.preferredContentSize = self.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
}
```

If your layout is configured correctly, `systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)` will return the smallest possible size for your view, taking into account all of the margins and sub-views.

Comment: Thanks for advice. My `UITextView` was already constrained to margins:
 `Text View.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom;
Text View.leading = leadingMargin;
Text View.trailing = trailingMargin;
Bottom Layout Guide.top = Text View.bottom;`
And I've changed it to
`Text View.leading = leadingMargin - 20;
Text View.trailing = trailingMargin + 20;`
(top and bottom were left unchanged), now it's working properly.
So the exact problem was that I thought I should constrain my `UITextView` to the blue lines suggested by Xcode (which include margin) instead of the edges of the screen.